# C++ STL Containers- some questions on Types?

Tags: c++, types, stl, stack, containers

[image]

---

**1**. If **Queue** is basically a 'linked list' it should be the *Associative type*  and Deque should be also a *Associated type* as well, as both these Abstract data types fit in that category. Why is Queue a 'Adapter type' and Deque-'Sequential' type? Why are the types being mixed with other definitions?

**2.** Why is **Stack** an Adapter Type? Is it because it follows a Wrapper Pattern and stores flags?

---

Also If I am not making sense or am technically incorrect can you point it out?

**EDIT**: My definition of a Associative Type: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array - Go see Implementation Tab and the first sentence you will see 'linked list' data structures.

Comment: What is your definition of Associative type ?

Comment: You are probably talking about the [C++ standard library, not the STL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5205491/whats-this-stl-vs-c-standard-library-fight-all-about/5205571#5205571).

Comment: I can explain Queue: in the STL, the "queue" data structure places a wrapper around a different type (by default dequeue) so that you can only add objects to the beginning and remove them from the end. It could be a vector, linked list, or whatever you want.

Comment: Likewise with std::stack and `std::priority_queue`.

Comment: @H2CO3: In this particular case he might be talking about the STL, as all the types mentioned here do belong to the STL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you don't know what the word "associative" means.  Associative types associate one set of data with another.  Like names to people, so you can find a person by looking up their name.  `deque` could be called_similar_ to a linked list, which is just a sequence of objects, so it is a sequential container.  There's no object association going on.  Also keep in mind, the category is based on the *interface*, not the *implementation*.

I disagree with the use of "Adaptor" as a category, realistically, the adaptors give sequential containers a new interface, so that they no longer behave like containers and instead behave like something else entirely.  Namely, a queue, priority queue, or a stack.  Again, *Adaptors do not fulfill the container interface*. (Though they can still be considered containers, depending on your definition)

Despite the names, `deque` and `queue` have *nothing* in common.  The first is a sequential container that is optimized for pushing and popping at either end, but can do anything a vector can do.  `queue` is an interface for objects in a `queue`.

As a note, your list is missing the C++11 containers: `array` and `forward_list` are new sequential containers, `unordered_map`, `unordered_multimap`, `unordered_set`, and `unordered_multiset` are new associative containers.  There are no new container adaptors.